# Run script on startup for Old Linux kernel (3.0.0)

Tags: scripting, boot, linux-kernel, startup, version

I need to run a script on system startup, but the Linux version is very old, so:

1. There is no `rc.local`. Even when I created it and gave it a command, it was never run.
2. There is no `crontab` at all.
3. Adding the script to `init.d` also didn't produce any result.
4. Obviously there is no Upstart app, and it's not possible to install as I can only access the device through ssh.

I'm sure the script itself works, as it works when I manually run it of course. The device is an embedded Linux device (Ettus E100, [link](http://www.ettus.com/product/details/UE100-KIT)). My Linux version is 3.0.0, and here is the exact version:

1. `$ cat /proc/version` returns:
   `Linux version 3.0.0 (oe-classic@oebuild) (gcc version 4.5.3 20110311 (prerelease) (GCC) ) #1 Thu Mar 28 18:15:38 PDT 2013`.
2. `$ dmesg | head -1` returns: 
   `[    0.000000] Linux version 3.0.0 (oe-classic@oebuild) (gcc version 4.5.3 20110311 (prerelease) (GCC) ) #1 Thu Mar 28 18:15:38 PDT 2013`.
3. `$ runlevel` returns: `N 5`.
4. `$ cat /etc/issue` returns nothing.
5. `$ cat /etc/*-release` returns error 'No such file or directory'.
6. `$ lsb_release -a` returns error 'command not found'.
7. `$ uname -a` returns: `Linux ettus-e1xx 3.0.0 #1 Thu Mar 28 18:15:38 PDT 2013 armv7l GNU/Linux`.

Not sure how else to check my distribution.

Are there any alternative means to get the script to run at startup?

Comment: rc.local *is* ancient, however not all Linux distributions use it. Please include in the description of the problem the Linux distribution. Also show us the ouput of the command "runlevel"

Comment: embedded Linux?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro   Hello, I edited the answer, and yes, it's embedded Linux.

Comment: Interesting, running arm at home too, though it is Debian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running embedded Linux, so it is somewhat limited in functionality. You seem however to have Sys V init, so we can emulate an rc.local for you.

Create a file `/etc/rc.local` with the instructions you need, and run this command:

```
#ln -s /etc/rc.local /etc/rc5.d/S99rclocal
```

or if you have sudo:

```
$sudo ln -s /etc/rc.local /etc/rc5.d/S99rclocal
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly!! I tried to link it to the rc5.d, but not the S99rclocal one.

Answer (score 0):

If your server use the original System V init daemon, you can use as well the `/etc/inittab` file.